# How to get an "untouched" window object?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a bookmarklet that makes use of the window.open method.

Sometimes websites modify this method so I cannot predict the behaviour of running the bookmarklet.

Is there any way to get an "untouched" window object?

I tried injecting a new iframe and getting the window object from this but then chrome is blocking the popup (see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=932884).

```
window.open("http://example.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `window.open` method is native code or not by using `.toString()` and checking if `[native code]` is present.

```
window.open.toString()
// returns: "function open() { [native code] }"

window.open.toString().includes('[native code]')
// returns: true

window.open = function() { console.log('ding!'); }
window.open.toString().includes('[native code]')
// returns: false
```

Additionally, you can reasonably ensure `.toString()` hasn't been overridden by calling it from the prototype.

```
Function.prototype.toString.call(window.open).includes('[native code]')
```

Comment: This actually helps me a lot. Thank you

Comment: Some improvements: var a = Function.prototype.toString.call(window.open); var b = String.prototype.replace.call(a, /\s/g,'') == 'functionopen(){[nativecode]}';

Comment: And the following should be true: typeof(window.open) == "function"

Comment: It is not 100% safe but it prevents the window.open method from having detrimental code.

Comment: @JuliusS. great! don't forget to mark the answer correct.